# Designing a recurrent neural network architecture

Tags: java, graph, architecture, neural-network

I'm making a recurrent neural network framework in Java and I'm having difficulty deciding whether to load connectivity information onto the neurons or onto the network class itself. The two designs I'm considering are as follows:

1) Class Network holds a list of lists of Node classes (a vertex list). To run the neural network, the network class activates all Nodes connected to the input Nodes and continually activates adjacent Nodes using the vertex list until all paths converge on the output Nodes.

2) Class Network holds a list of Nodes. Each Node holds a list of input Nodes that it is connected to. To run the neural network, the network class activates the output Nodes which recursively activate adjacent Nodes and returns the output.

I'm implementing the NEAT algorithm, so there is no backpropagation to handle.
The first option seems like it would be more complicated and the second seems like a poor choice of architecture and might lead to a lot of redundant computation.

I'm wondering if I'm approaching this all wrong, or at least if there is a clear winner out of these two options.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I can go with the first option. I agree the second one is sounds a poor choice. Remember the OO hides complexity (buries it inside the class someone can say) is not necessary to anyone to know to use the object/class itself. In a ideal world a good OO implementation ill need a bit more work to build from scratch but is not more complicated and get the benefits of being more easy to maintain and understand.